# What's the difference between 'delete' and 'destroy' in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have confused between using `delete` and `destroy` in my case when you want to delete an object, for example:

**app.h**

```
#include "taskBarIcon.h"
class myApp: public wxApp{
public:
    // ....
private:
    CTaskBarIcon *m_pTaskbar; // = NULL
};
```

**app.cpp**

```
int myApp::OnExit() {
    if (m_pTaskbar != NULL) {
        delete m_pTaskbar; // <-- The problem here
        m_pTaskbar = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
int myApp::OnRun() {
    mainFrm *_mainFrm = mainFrm::getInstance(); // The main window
    _mainFrm->Show(false);
    m_pTaskbar = new CTaskBarIcon(_mainFrm);
    m_pTaskbar->SetIcon(wxIcon("appIcon"), _mainFrm->GetTitle());      
    return wxApp::OnRun();
}
```

**CTaskBarIcon.cpp**

```
void CTaskBarIcon::rightButton_Click(wxTaskBarIconEvent & event) {
    PopupMenu(CreatePopupMenu());
}

void CTaskBarIcon::popupMenu_showWindow(wxCommandEvent & event) {
    m_pHandler->Iconize(false); // 'm_pHandler' is the main window
    m_pHandler->Show();
    m_pHandler->Raise();
    this->Destroy();
}

void CTaskBarIcon::popupMenu_showAbout(wxCommandEvent & event) {
    aboutFrm aboutWindow(m_pHandler, "About");
    aboutWindow.ShowModal();
    aboutWindow.Raise();
}

void CTaskBarIcon::popupMenu_exit(wxCommandEvent & event) {
    m_pHandler->Close(true);
    this->Destroy();
}
```

The previous code cause a runtime error when quitting the program and the reason for that is to delete the member variable `m_pTaskbar`:

```
// app.cpp
int myApp::OnExit() {
    if (m_pTaskbar != NULL) {
        delete m_pTaskbar; // <-- The problem here
        m_pTaskbar = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But note that I was used `this->Destroy()` in different places in `CTaskBarIcon.cpp` codes.

**What the difference between `delete` and `destroy`, and are they do the same thing?**

Comment: `delete` is a C++ keyword which is covered in any introductory C++ learning material. I have no idea what `Destroy()` is, but it's probably covered in WxWidgets's documentation.

Comment: `delete` is a keyword and is part of the [delete expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete).  `Destroy` is a member function and you'll have to find it to see what it does.

Comment: `delete` is to be used to release the memory, that was `new`ed, while `Destroy`, in your case, is a class method, and you would need to look at its implementation to know what it does.

Comment: Destroy is a function which is a member of `CTaskBarIcon`. You can look up what it does in either the documentation or the source code. `delete` is an operator that frees memory and calls the destructor of an object previously allocated with `new`. Instead `new` and `delete` you should use smart pointers, though.

Comment: I do not see the reason to downvote this question.

Comment: @Swordfish In this case OP shouldn't use smart pointers, or atleast, not the default deallocator.

Comment: @Swordfish your answer not applicable here. The question is specifically about vxwidgets framework, and one should not use smart pointers for vxwidget-managed pointer.

Comment: @MikeBorkland That's not true

Comment: TL;DR `Destroy()` is work around  the dangling reference problem in asynchronous framework, it delays deletion of object to the point where it safely can be done.

Answer (score 11):

WXWidgets has an explanation on their [wiki](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/overview_windowdeletion.html):

> The wxCloseEvent handler should only call `wxWindow::Destroy()` to delete
>   the window, and not use the `delete` operator. This is because for some
>   window classes, wxWidgets delays actual deletion of the window until
>   all events have been processed, since otherwise there is the danger
>   that events will be sent to a non-existent window.

The core keeps a list of open windows and it will decide when to actually call `delete` on these objects. The client should never call it themselves directly.

Comment: similar with Qt's `deleteLater()` if you delete Widget in context where an event is handled or a nest event loop is created. Framework takes ownership of some aspects of object and deleting it without removing all dangling references from framework is incorrect. The limitation comes from fact that the deletion happens in context where possibly a cached copy of reference or pointer to deleted object exists.

Comment: This is perfectly correct, just notice that this explanation is not from the [wiki](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/) but from the [official documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/) site.